# .NET SmtpMail compared with .NET SmtpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, smtp, smtpclient

I am working with a .NET 4.0 application which uses the `System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail` class to send emails that we generate, specifying a BodyFormat of `MailFormat.Html`.

The problem with this approach is that when we generate the email (using `MailFormat.Html`), the protocol only seems to allow 76 characters per line. Upon exceeding that limit, the rest of the line seems to get cut off and an exclamation mark gets rendered in its place.

This is problematic for us, and makes the code extremely difficult to improve and refactor. I noticed that Visual Studio complains that the SmtpMail class is obsolete, and that the recommended alternative is the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` class. I have been wondering whether changing to use the newer class would offer any improvements, especially in the number of characters that can exist on any single line - or perhaps this is a problem with the SMTP protocol that can't be overcome.

Documentation exists for both of these classes but there is no description of the differences between the classes and how the functionality and behaviour differs between the two.

Can anyone advise on the differences between the obsolete and the newer class for sending emails and also whether it is possible to overcome the 76 character per line limit.

Thank you

Comment: From MSDN about the `System.Web.Mail` namespace: `The classes in this namespace have been deprecated. Use the System.Net.Mail namespace instead`

Comment: How is this a duplicate? My question contains a specific query regarding a character limit in an API, the other alleged duplicate questions do not answer this query.

Comment: Also one of the alleged duplicate questions is itself marked as a duplicate of one of the other referenced questions.

Comment: I addressed the character limit in my answer (note you could have discovered if there's a character limit with just a little experimentation). And just because one of the questions itself is a duplicate doesn't mean it's useless in answering your question.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you from experience that there is no character line limit in using `System.Net.Mail`. It's recommended for use, `System.Web.Mail` is obsolete. The way forward is clear.

As for specific API differences, `System.Web.Mail` is COM based, while `System.Net.Mail` is in fully managed code. If you want to see different function/property names, then the MSDN documentation is available to you.

- [System.Web.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN
- [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN